# How do i use a variable in a switch statement *updated *

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am trying to use a variable in my switch statement as it makes the player movement smooth. This is my smooth player movement code.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyPressedUp);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,movehero);
    function keyPressedDown(event:KeyboardEvent){
if(event.keyCode==37){leftArrow = true;}
else if (event.keyCode == 39){rightArrow=true;}
else if(event.keyCode ==38){upArrow = true;}
else if(event.keyCode ==40){downArrow = true;}
}

    function keyPressedUp(event:KeyboardEvent){
if(event.keyCode==37){leftArrow = false;}
else if (event.keyCode == 39){rightArrow=false;}
else if(event.keyCode ==38){upArrow = false;}
else if(event.keyCode ==40){downArrow = false;}
    }

    function movehero(event:Event){
if(leftArrow){hero.x -= 10;}
if(rightArrow){hero.x += 10;}
if(upArrow){hero.y -= 10;}
if(downArrow){hero.y += 10;}
}
```

I am trying to implement it into my existing code. i need the switch statements for collision.

This code works fine but player movement is very slugish.

Thanks in advance

```
I am trying to acheive something like this, but this does not work 

 var leftArrow:Boolean= false;
 var rightArrow:Boolean= false;
 var upArrow:Boolean= false;
 var downArrow:Boolean=false;


    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyPressedUp);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,movehero);

    function keyPressedDown(event:KeyboardEvent){
if(event.keyCode==37){leftArrow = true;}
else if (event.keyCode == 39){rightArrow=true;}
else if(event.keyCode ==38){upArrow = true;}
else if(event.keyCode ==40){downArrow = true;}
}

    function keyPressedUp(event:KeyboardEvent){
if(event.keyCode==37){leftArrow = false;}
else if (event.keyCode == 39){rightArrow=false;}
else if(event.keyCode ==38){upArrow = false;}
else if(event.keyCode ==40){downArrow = false;}
    }

    function movehero(event:Event){

switch(event){
    case leftArrow:
    hero.x -=10;
    break;

    case rightArrow:
    hero.x +=10;
    break;

    case upArrow:
    hero.y -=10;
    break;

    case downArrow:
    hero.y += 10;
    break;

    default  :
    break;
}
```

}

Comment: -1 vague question, poorly researched.

Comment: Sorry i have updated my question.

Comment: http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/594292?footer_feature=audio

This is my game so far, its in early stages and u can see that the movement is pretty terrible and makes it hard to get past enemies.

And i want to implement smooth player movement into code but it has to be in switch statements as thats how my collision code is worked.

Comment: Well i can get player movement smooth. If its not implemted in a switch statemen, But it has to be in a switch statement as it is needed for my collision.

So no its to see how to implement my smooth code into a switch statement.

I updated the question so you can see what i mean.

Comment: Thanks for the help i think i'v got it, i'l up date my question with the answer. if  u take it and post it, i'l mark it as correct.

Comment: I wouldn't do that - it's completely acceptable to post a solution to your own question if you find it and mark it as correct in 2 days :)

Comment: For some i thought i had to have 100 rep to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyPressedUp);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,movehero);

function keyPressedDown(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(event.keyCode==37) leftArrow = true;
    else if(event.keyCode == 39) rightArrow = true;
    else if(event.keyCode ==38) upArrow = true;
    else if(event.keyCode ==40) downArrow = true;
}

function keyPressedUp(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(event.keyCode == 37) leftArrow = false;
    else if (event.keyCode == 39) rightArrow = false;
    else if(event.keyCode == 38) upArrow = false;
    else if(event.keyCode == 40) downArrow = false;
}

function movehero(event:Event)
{
    switch(true)
    {
        case (leftArrow):
            hero.x -=10;
            break;

        case (rightArrow):
            hero.x +=10;
            break;

        case (upArrow) :
            hero.y -=10;
            break;

        case (downArrow):
            hero.y += 10;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a good pattern to set the boolean variables of direction, when using keyboards. Try this code of function movehero :

```
function movehero(event:Event)
{    
        if (this.leftArrow):
            hero.x -= 10 ;

        if (this.rightArrow)
            hero.x += 10 ;

        if (this.upArrow)
            hero.y -= 10 ;

        if (this.downArrow)
            hero.y += 10 ;
}
```

Note: If you really want to make your hero move smoothly, increase the frame rate of your game, and decrease the speed. So, the hero will perform **MORE SMALL** steps, that appears to be smooth movement, instead of **FEWER**, but **BIG** steps.

So, instead of incrementing + 10, **make it +2 and increase the frame rate**. 30-40 fps is pretty enough for smooth movement.

Wish you good luck, hope it helps :)